# Replacing a character in dataframe string columns in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, regexp-replace

I have a task to remove all line delimiters (\n) from all string columns in a table.
The number of table columns is unknown, the code should process any table.

I wrote the code that would go through all columns in a loop, retrieve a column data type and replace the line delimiter:

```
  //let's assume we already have a dataframe 'df' that can contain any table
  df.cache()
  val dfTypes = df.dtypes
  for ( i <- 0 to (dfTypes.length - 1)) {
    var tupCol = dfTypes(i)
    if (tupCol._2 == "StringType" )
      df.unpersist()
      df = df.withColumn(tupCol._1, regexp_replace(col(tupCol._1), "\n", " "))
      df.cache()
  }
  df.unpersist()
```

The code itself works fine, but when I run this code for ~50 tables in parallel  I constantly get the following error for one random table:

```
18/11/20 04:31:41 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 9.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 29, ip-10-114-4-145.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 1): java.io.IOException: No space left on device
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
at org.apache.spark.storage.TimeTrackingOutputStream.write(TimeTrackingOutputStream.java:58)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.finish(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:260)
at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.close(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:190)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeRowSerializerInstance$$anon$1.close(UnsafeRowSerializer.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.commitAndGet(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:156)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I can run less or more than 50 jobs but the only one (random) keeps failing.

The jobs are running on EMR cluster with the following configuration:

Master node: r4.2xlarge x 1

Core nodes:  m5.2xlarge x 3

Task nodes:  m5.2xlarge x (Autoscaling from 1 to 10)

I think my code consumes a lot of memory and disc space because it creates new dataframes in a loop. But I do not see any other solution to process a table without knowing a number of string columns. 
I need a suggestion of how optimize the code.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need _cache_ after every change, remember that Spark is lazy on its processing. Thus, it doesn't really need to build a new **DF** for each iteration, but instead let spark build the Graph of all changes and the run it - I'm sure it will update all columns at once, without consuming too much memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Luis. I've decided to use Scala foldLeft method which can update all columns at once.